# APEX can't access login page fresh windows fresh install

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle18c

I am trying to install apex 18 on oracle database 18 on a fresh windows 10 the installation process goes with no errors and all set

and there is not other software that may result in port interfere

when I installed the oracle I did not create a container there is no orclpdb installed some tutorials mentioned that I should not create it in order to install the apex

when I run the command to check apex status it returns valid

I installed the apex using

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

@apexins sysaux sysaux temp /i/

@apexldimg c:\software

@apexconf
```

please help this is my 18th try I have changed os changed oracle version and apex I know this is an already asked question but noun of the previous solutions helped me

when I try localhost:8081/apex/apex_admin I get a user name and password dialog:

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to install APEX in a PDB, not in the container.

Comment: I did not create a container when I install the oracle database so I guess I didn't install it on a container

Comment: I can't read your language, but - that looks like Apex admin login page. You connected to it, so you got it. So what's the problem? Username is INTERNAL, and password is what you set it to during installation. If you don't know it, connect (via SQL*Plus) as SYS and run @`apxchpwd.sql` file.

Comment: Yes it is apex admin page but I keep get the credentials massage I can't log in or load the admin page INTERAL and my password did not work keep getting same massage